# Steps after automatic merge fails / manual merge

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull

So if I do a

```
git pull origin master
```

and then the automatic merge fails

I then manually merge, by removing the git notation from conflicted files, and "cherry picking" what I want, and don't want.

But after I do the manual merge, what is the right steps to take next?

My guess is:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "manually merged conflicted files"
```

is that correct, or should I take another step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that is the correct sequence of actions

1. do a `git pull origin master`
2. if no conflicts, jump to 5
3. resolve conflicts, keep your/remote changes as applicable
4. Add and commit the conflicted files using `git add conflicted_file_1 conflicted_file_2 && git commit -m "Resolved merge conflicts"`
5. Update your branch on the remote using `git push origin master`

Note that cherry picking has a [different meaning in git terminology](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

Also, if possible, try to explore [a rebase based flow with feature branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase/), to keep your history saner in the long term.

Comment: thanks what i dont really understand is having to (re) add the resolved conflicted files

Comment: does it somehow leave the conflicted files out?

Comment: @AlexMills A merge always creates a new commit, unless the changes to be applied can be fast forwarded (pull = fetch + merge). In case of conflicts, the merge commit is simply not created, git merges files to the maximum extent possible, and then leaves it to you the user to resolve the conflicts, add the conflicted files and manually create the merge commit.

Comment: @AlexMills if you are on linux, install `gitk` (google for tools in other dev environment), and then run `gitk` from your repo. You will see the commit graph for the branch, which will help in visualization

Comment: @AlexMills If that helped, don't forget to accept the answer :)